# What kind of tunnel was One Thing Leads to Another filmed in?

Tags: film-location, music-video

Most of the video for the song *[One Thing Leads to Another](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JHYIGy1dyd8)* by *The Fixx* appears to have been shot in what looks like a concrete tunnel with a row of lights attached to the ceiling- does anyone have any idea what purpose this tunnel originally served?

[image]

Comment: An interesting question. It's too well lit to be a storm drain and too narrow for pedestrians.

Comment: Maybe a runoff tunnel where they've installed extra lighting.

Comment: @Valorum It’s too wide to be part of the interior of the Hoover Dam. But perhaps it’s some similar location.

Comment: Actually… go to 5:10 in this: https://youtu.be/YHg2tTo5Zlo?si=aKLB1A7T75NqM213 That part of the dam has fewer lights per foot though.

Comment: Hmm... given they're from London I was tempted to say a service tunnel in the Channel Tunnel (would have thought they'd be wider), but given it was done in 1982 I'd say not :)